# parsing times in R and extracting elements that meet certain criteria

Tags: r, datetime

I have a subset of a large dataframe with 2 columns that looks something like this

```
c1                      c2
gym1               Thu:8:00 AM -10:30 PM;Fri: 8:00 AM -9:00 PM
gym2               Wed:7:00 AM-4:00 PM
gym3               Mon:12:00 PM - 6:00 PM;Tue:12:00 PM - 7:00 PM;Wed:10:00 AM -10:00 PM
gym4               Sat:8:00 AM -10:30 PM;Sun: 8:00 AM -9:00 PM
gym5               Sat:8:00 AM -10:30 PM;Sun: 8:00 AM -12:00 PM
```

c1 contain gym names and c2 contain the days of the week and times they are open in character format.

How would I go about parsing c2 and 1. finding which gyms are open for greater than x hours and 2. finding which gyms open after 9am? I'm guessing I would add two columns at the end of my dataframe with TRUE or FALSE values but don't know how I would get to that point.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please consider normalizing your data, and get each open range, for each gym, onto a separate row of your data frame.  Someone may give you an amswer with your data as is, but you should seriously consider changing your design.

Comment: I think a solution to this will likely use `strsplit(...,";")`, `strsplit(..."-")` (plus repeat-weekday), `as.POSIXct(...)`; and some form of data.frame wide-to-tall conversion (e.g., `tidyr::gather`). But the only reason I'd consider doing all of that is if you have absolutely no control over the format of the data coming in like this.

Comment: yea..unfortunately I have no control over the format of the incoming data.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df=dat%>%tidytext::unnest_tokens(word, c2, token = strsplit, split = ";")%>%
    separate(word,c("day","open_time","close_time"),"(?<=[a-z]):|-")%>%
    mutate(duration=strptime(close_time,"%I:%M %p")-strptime(open_time,"%I:%M %p"))
  df
   c1 day open_time close_time   duration
1 gym1 thu  8:00 am    10:30 pm 14.5 hours
2 gym1 fri  8:00 am     9:00 pm 13.0 hours
3 gym2 wed   7:00 am    4:00 pm  9.0 hours
4 gym3 mon 12:00 pm     6:00 pm  6.0 hours
5 gym3 tue 12:00 pm     7:00 pm  7.0 hours
6 gym3 wed 10:00 am    10:00 pm 12.0 hours
7 gym4 sat  8:00 am    10:30 pm 14.5 hours
8 gym4 sun  8:00 am     9:00 pm 13.0 hours

df%>%group_by(c1)%>%
     mutate(openafter9=as.numeric(format(strptime(open_time,"%I:%M %p"),"%I"))>9,
             Tot_Hrs_opn=sum(duration))##You can decide to use summarize but remember opening hour may depend on the day so you need to be careful
# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   c1 [4]
     c1   day open_time close_time   duration openafter9 Tot_Hrs_opn
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <time>      <lgl>      <time>
1  gym1   thu  8:00 am    10:30 pm 14.5 hours      FALSE  27.5 hours
2  gym1   fri  8:00 am     9:00 pm 13.0 hours      FALSE  27.5 hours
3  gym2   wed   7:00 am    4:00 pm  9.0 hours      FALSE   9.0 hours
4  gym3   mon 12:00 pm     6:00 pm  6.0 hours       TRUE  25.0 hours
5  gym3   tue 12:00 pm     7:00 pm  7.0 hours       TRUE  25.0 hours
6  gym3   wed 10:00 am    10:00 pm 12.0 hours       TRUE  25.0 hours
7  gym4   sat  8:00 am    10:30 pm 14.5 hours      FALSE  27.5 hours
8  gym4   sun  8:00 am     9:00 pm 13.0 hours      FALSE  27.5 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example is very long winded and could be certainly simplified. However, I believe it does what you request.

It assumes that your dates all conform to the below (inconsistent formatted) fashion.

It returns a larger data frame then expected, as it provides:

Opening time for each day
 Closing time for each day
 Duration of how long the gym is open each day
 If the gym is open greater than x hours on that particular day
 Finally it identifies if the gym is open after (or on) 9am on any day
 and Finally it identifies if the gym is open greater than x hours on any day

```
df<-data.frame(c1=c("gym1","gym2","gym3","gym4","gym5"),c2=c("Thu:8:00 AM -10:30 PM;Fri: 8:00 AM -9:00 PM",
    "Wed:7:00 AM-4:00 PM",
    "Mon:12:00 PM - 6:00 PM;Tue:12:00 PM - 7:00 PM;Wed:10:00 AM -10:00 PM",
    "Sat:8:00 AM -10:30 PM;Sun: 8:00 AM -9:00 PM",
    "Sat:8:00 AM -10:30 PM;Sun: 8:00 AM -12:00 PM"))

# Remove white space to standardise
df$c2 <- gsub(" +","",df$c2)

# standardise time into hh:mm
df$c2 <- gsub(":([1-9]):",":0\\1:",df$c2)
df$c2 <- gsub("-([1-9]):","-0\\1:",df$c2)
# Lowercase the text
df$c2 <- tolower(df$c2 )

library(stringr)

# Open for greater than x hours
x <- 7

for(i in c("mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat","sun")) {
    tmp <- data.frame(stringr::str_locate(df$c2,i))["end"]
    df <- cbind(df,tmp)
    df[,paste0(i,"_open")] <- NA
    df[,paste0(i,"_closed")] <- NA
    df[!is.na(df$end),paste0(i,"_open")] <- str_sub(df$c2[!is.na(df$end)],df$end[!is.na(df$end)]+2,df$end[!is.na(df$end)]+8)
    df[!is.na(df$end),paste0(i,"_closed")] <- str_sub(df$c2[!is.na(df$end)],df$end[!is.na(df$end)]+10,df$end[!is.na(df$end)]+16)

    df[,paste0(i,"_duration")] <- NA
    df[,paste0(i,"_duration")] <-
    as.numeric(difftime(
        strptime(df[,paste0(i,"_closed")], "%I:%M%p" ),
        strptime(df[,paste0(i,"_open")], "%I:%M%p" ),
        units='hours')
    )
    # open for greater than x?
    df[,paste0(i,"_open_greater_than_x_hours")] <- FALSE
    df[which(df[,paste0(i,"_duration")] >= x),paste0(i,"_open_greater_than_x_hours")] <- TRUE

    # open after 9 am?
    df[,paste0(i,"_open_after_9am")] <- FALSE
    df[,paste0(i,"_open_after_9am")] <- strptime(df[,paste0(i,"_open")], "%I:%M%p" )  >= strptime("09:00am", "%I:%M%p" ) 

    df$end <- NULL
}

# Determine if a gym opens after (or at) 9am on at least one day
df$any_day_open_after_9am <- rowSums(df[,names(df)[grepl("after_9",names(df))]],na.rm = T) > 1

# Determine if a gym is open for greater than x hours on at least one day
df$open_greater_than_x_hours <- rowSums(df[,names(df)[grepl("open_greater_tha",names(df))]],na.rm = T) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to get the data into a tidier format.

`strsplit` the days into a list-column of character vectors. Then `unnest` to have a row for each day.

Then it's a lot more cleaning.

```
library("lubridate")
library("tidyverse")

df <- read_table("c1                 c2
gym1               Thu:8:00 AM -10:30 PM;Fri: 8:00 AM -9:00 PM
gym2               Wed:7:00 AM-4:00 PM
gym3               Mon:12:00 PM - 6:00 PM;Tue:12:00 PM - 7:00 PM;Wed:10:00 AM -10:00 PM
gym4               Sat:8:00 AM -10:30 PM;Sun: 8:00 AM -9:00 PM
gym5               Sat:8:00 AM -10:30 PM;Sun: 8:00 AM -12:00 PM
")

df_tidied <-
  df %>%
  mutate(c2 = strsplit(c2, ";")) %>%
  unnest %>%
  separate(c2, c("open_day", "times"), sep = ":", extra = "merge") %>%
  mutate(times = gsub(" ", "", times)) %>%
  separate(times, c("open_time", "close_time"), sep = "-") %>%
  mutate(
    open_time = parse_date_time(open_time, "%I:%M%p"),
    close_time = coalesce(
      parse_date_time(close_time, "%I:%M%p"),
      open_time + hours(1)),
    opening_hours = close_time - open_time)
df_tidied
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    c1    open_day open_time           close_time          opening_hours
#>    <chr> <chr>    <dttm>              <dttm>              <time>       
#>  1 gym1  Thu      0000-01-01 08:00:00 0000-01-01 22:30:00 14.5         
#>  2 gym1  Fri      0000-01-01 08:00:00 0000-01-01 21:00:00 13           
#>  3 gym2  Wed      0000-01-01 07:00:00 0000-01-01 16:00:00 9            
#>  4 gym3  Mon      0000-01-01 12:00:00 0000-01-01 18:00:00 6            
#>  5 gym3  Tue      0000-01-01 12:00:00 0000-01-01 19:00:00 7            
#>  6 gym3  Wed      0000-01-01 10:00:00 0000-01-01 11:00:00 1            
#>  7 gym4  Sat      0000-01-01 08:00:00 0000-01-01 22:30:00 14.5         
#>  8 gym4  Sun      0000-01-01 08:00:00 0000-01-01 21:00:00 13           
#>  9 gym5  Sat      0000-01-01 08:00:00 0000-01-01 22:30:00 14.5         
#> 10 gym5  Sun      0000-01-01 08:00:00 0000-01-01 12:00:00 4
```

Once it's tidy, just sum (`tally`) the `opening_hours` by `c1`.

```
df_tidied %>%
  group_by(c1) %>%
  tally(opening_hours)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   c1    n     
#>   <chr> <time>
#> 1 gym1  27.5  
#> 2 gym2  9     
#> 3 gym3  14    
#> 4 gym4  27.5  
#> 5 gym5  18.5
```